# C++ Морской Бой - некоторые моменты

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Хочу написать консольную игру морской бой. Я тут немножко понаписал код, но не реализовал некоторые моменты. Не обращайте внимание на такое кол-во подключенных библиотек, мне так просто спокойнее)

В моей наработке есть поле (двумерный массив) разделенное на 2 части (от 1 до 5 строки вражеская, от 6 и 10 строки моя часть) в котором показываются однопалубные корабли в виде "1" и пустые ячейки в виде "0". Я могу ввести координаты по строке и столбцу и "уничтожить" данные корабли (ввод для меня разрешен от 1 до 5 строк, а для бота от 6 до 10). При уничтожении, их значении меняется на "5" на одну итерацию, чтобы было видно, что по нему стреляли и позже на "0", когда она превратится в пустое место. При уничтожении всех кораблей игра оканчивается и объявляется победа

То с чем я не могу справиться и из-за чего пишу сюда. Требуется, чтобы у каждого (меня и бота) было по 5 штук - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - палубных кораблей расставленных по полю 10х10, а не 1 палубных как в данный момент и также, когда бот попадает по моему кораблю, он стрелял на одну ячейку дальше в рандомном направлении, а не в случайную ячейку по всей карте его атаки, как сейчас. Также, не знаю как скрыть поле которое я атакую, чтобы показывались только подбитые мной корабли. Жду советов от знающих. Прошу не кидайте ссылки на чужие проекты, мне нужно объяснить на основе моего кода. Благодарю

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>

using namespace std;

const int SIZEf = 10;
int field[SIZEf][SIZEf] = {};

HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

char s1[256];

void GotoXY(int X, int Y)
{
    COORD coord = { X, Y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coord);
}

void menu()
{
    int f = 1, k, code;

    cout << "\n\n"; // * фигура
    for (int x = 0; x < 13; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 13; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == y && y < 13 / 2 || x + y == 13 - 1 && y > 13 / 2 - 1)
            {
                cout << "    \t* ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "    \t  ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    } // *

    GotoXY(27, 12);
    cout << "\t\t\t--> Новая игра <--";
    GotoXY(30, 13);
    cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
    cout << "\n\n\t\t«Морской бой» — игра для двух участников, в которой игроки по очереди называют координаты на неизвестной им карте соперника. Если у соперника по этим координатам имеется корабль (координаты заняты), то корабль или его часть «топится», а попавший получает право сделать ещё один ход";
    do
    {
        k = 0;
        code = _getch();
        if (code == 224 || code == 0)
        {
            code = _getch();
        }

        if (code == 80)
        {
            f = f * (-1);
            if (f == 1)
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t--> Новая игра <--";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
            }
            else if (f == 2)
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t    Новая игра    ";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
            }
            else
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t    Новая игра    ";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t   --> Выход <--";
            }
        }
        else if (code == 72)
        {
            f = f * (-1);
            if (f == 1)
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t--> Новая игра <--";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
            }
            else if (f == 2)
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t    Новая игра    ";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
            }
            else
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t    Новая игра    ";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t   --> Выход <--";
            }
        }
        else if (code == 13)
        {
            k = 1;
        }
        cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;
    }

    while (k == 0);
    {
        if (f != 1)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void figure1()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) // * Создали квадрат
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == 15 - 1 || y == 0 || y == 15 - 1)
            {
                cout << "    \t* ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "    \t ";
            }
            if (x == 6) // ** Опускаемся ниже, чтобы написать текст внутри квадрата
            {
                cout << "      \t\t\t\t\t";
                string h = "Морской Бой!";
                for (int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++)
                {
                    Sleep(60);
                    cout << h[i];
                }
                break;
            } // **
        }
        cout << endl; // эндл чтобы создавать строки для квадрата
    }
    Sleep(1500); // пауза // *
    cout << "\a"; // звук переключения меню
}

void reminder1()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t    Напоминание:\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t    Нажмите крестик сверху, чтобы выйти из игры\n\t\t\t       При этом достижения не сохраняются!";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t";
    string h = "................................."; // ** Искусственное ожидание с помощью имитации загрузки визуализированное точками
    for (int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++)
    {
        Sleep(50);
        cout << h[i];
    } // **
    cout << "\n\n";
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
}

void win()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
    {
        if (x <= 1)
        {
            system("Color 05");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tП";
            system("Color 15");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " о";
            system("Color 25");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " з";
            system("Color 35");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " д";
            system("Color 48");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " р";
            system("Color 65");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " а";
            system("Color 85");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " в";
            system("Color 93");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " л";
            system("Color A5");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " я";
            system("Color B5");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " е";
            system("Color C0");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " м";
            system("Color E5");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tВ";
            system("Color F5");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " а";
            system("Color 75");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " с";
            Sleep(200);
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) // * Создали квадрат
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
                {
                    if (x == 0 || x == 15 - 1 || y == 0 || y == 15 - 1)
                    {
                        cout << "    \t* ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "    \t ";
                    }
                    if (x == 6) // ** Опускаемся ниже, чтобы написать текст внутри квадрата
                    {
                        cout << "      \t\t\t\t\t";
                        string h = "Вы выиграли!";
                        for (int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++)
                        {
                            Sleep(60);
                            cout << h[i];
                        }
                        break;
                    } // **
                }
                cout << endl; // эндл чтобы создавать строки для квадрата
            } // *
        }
    }
}

void ad() // Небольшая реклама 1
{
    system("cls");
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) // * Создали квадрат
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == 15 - 1 || y == 0 || y == 15 - 1)
            {
                cout << "    \t* ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "    \t ";
            }
            if (x == 6) // ** Опускаемся ниже, чтобы написать текст внутри квадрата
            {
                cout << "      \t\t\t\tНебольшая рекламная интеграция:\n\n      \t\t\t\t             ";
                string h = "Ставки на Рамина! Один только Рамин!\n\n      \t\t\t\t             Большие выигрыши! Один только Рамин!\n\n      \t\t\t\t             Быстрые решения! Один только Рамин!\n\n      \t\t\t\t             Надежный президент! Один только Рамин!\n\n      \t\t\t\t               Голосуйте за одного только Рамина\n\n      \t\t\t\t                     Земля ему пухом...\n\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++)
                {
                    Sleep(40);
                    cout << h[i];
                }
                break;
            } // **
        }
        cout << endl; // эндл чтобы создавать строки для квадрата
    } //
    Sleep(3300);
    system("cls");
}

void tableShow()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl << "\t\t\t\t";
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZEf; i++)
    {
        counter++;
        cout << counter;
        cout << "\t";
    }
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t==========================================================================";

    counter = 0;

    cout << endl << endl << "\t\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZEf; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZEf; j++)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && j == 0)
            {
                counter++;
                cout << "\t" << counter << " |";
            }
            cout << "\t" << field[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl << endl << endl << "\t\t";
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    system("Color 75");

    menu();
    figure1();
    reminder1();

    int x, y;

    int enemyShipCounter = 0; // * Расположение и количество вражеских кораблей
    while (true)
    {
        x = rand() % SIZEf;
        if (x <= 4)
        {
            y = rand() % SIZEf;
            field[x][y] = 1;
            enemyShipCounter++;
            if (enemyShipCounter == 10)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    } // *


    int myShipCounter = 0; // * Расположение и количество моих кораблей
    while (true)
    {
        x = rand() % SIZEf;
        if (x >= 5)
        {
            y = rand() % SIZEf;
            field[x][y] = 1;
            myShipCounter++;
            if (myShipCounter == 10)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    } // *

    tableShow();

    bool isMyRound = false;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\t\tВведите координаты: ";
        do
        {
            cin >> x;
            cin >> y;
            if (x >= 6 || x <= 0 || y <= 0)
            {
                cout << "\n\t\t\t\tВведите координаты которые выше 6 строки (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), чтобы стрелять по вражескому полю!\n\n";
                cout << "\t\t\t\tВведите координаты: ";
            }
        } while (x >= 6 || x <= 0 || y <= 0);
        {
            x--;
            y--;
        }

        if (field[x][y] == 1)
        {
            cout << "\n\t\t\t\tВы попали по вражескому кораблю!\a" << endl;
            field[x][y] = 5;
            Sleep(3300);

            tableShow();

            field[x][y] = 0;

            bool ship_detect = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZEf - 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZEf; j++)
                {
                    if (field[i][j] == 1)
                    {
                        ship_detect = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (ship_detect == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ship_detect == false)
            {
                cout << "\t\tВы выиграли!!! Все корабли соперника потеплены!" << endl;
                Sleep(4000);
                win();
                Sleep(2000);
                ad();
                break;
            }
            isMyRound = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\t\t\t\tВы промахнулись!" << endl;
            field[x][y] = 0;
            isMyRound = false;
            Sleep(3400);
            tableShow();
        }

        while (isMyRound == false) // * ход бота
        {
            cout << "\t\tХод бота...\n\n";
            x = rand() % 5 + 6;
            y = rand() % 10 + 1;
            cout << "\t\t\t\tБот ввел координаты: x[" << x-- << "] и y[" << y-- << "]\n";

            if (field[x][y] == 1)
            {
                cout << "\n\t\t\t\tБот попал по нашему кораблю!\a" << endl;
                field[x][y] = 5;

                Sleep(5500);

                tableShow();

                field[x][y] = 0;

                bool ship_detect = false;
                for (int i = 6; i < SIZEf; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < SIZEf; j++)
                    {
                        if (field[i][j] == 1)
                        {
                            ship_detect = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ship_detect == true)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (ship_detect == false)
                {
                    cout << "\t\t\t\tБот выиграл!!! Все наши корабли потеплены!" << endl;
                    Sleep(5500);
                    ad();
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\n\t\t\t\tБот промахнулся! Ваша очередь..." << endl;
                isMyRound = true;
                field[x][y] = 0;
                Sleep(5500);
                tableShow();
            }
        } // *
    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вражеские корабли не отображались, пока их не подобьют в функции tableshow() измените код на:

```
void tableShow(){
system("cls");
cout << endl << endl << "\t\t\t\t";
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZEf; i++)
{
    counter++;
    cout << counter;
    cout << "\t";
}
cout << "\n\t\t\t\t==========================================================================";

counter = 0;

cout << endl << endl << "\t\t";
for (int i = 0; i < SIZEf; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZEf; j++)
    {
        if (i >= 0 && j == 0)
        {
            counter++;
            cout << "\t" << counter << " |";
        }
        if (field[i][j] == 5){
            cout << "\t" << field[i][j];
        }
        else if (i < 5){
            cout << "\t0";
        }
        else{
            cout << "\t" << field[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl << endl << "\t\t";
}
}
```

Замените цифру убитых кораблей на -1 для некоторых функций и для вида.
В функции main вам нужно добавить несколько переменных:

```
int Direction = -1;
bool BotHit = false;
bool BotHitForSecondBotHit = false;
bool SecondBotHit = false;
bool BotMiss[4] = {false, false, false, false}; //Попадание бота по четырём сторонам
```

Далее заменить в ходе бота все x и y на BotX и BotY. После этого добавить следующий код:

```
cout << "\t\tХод бота...\n\n";
        if (BotHit == true){
            if (SecondBotHit == false){
                while (true){
                    Direction = 1 + rand() % 4;
                    if (Direction == 1 && BotMiss[0] == false && BotY > 0){
                        BotY--; //Стреляет левее
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 2 && BotMiss[1] == false && BotX > 5){
                        BotX--; //Стреляет выше
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 3 && BotMiss[2] == false && BotY < 9){
                        BotY++; //Стреляет правее
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 4 && BotMiss[3] == false && BotX < 9){
                        BotX++; //Стреляет ниже
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        BotMiss[Direction - 1] = true; //Если никуда не получилось выстрелить
                    }
                    if (BotMiss[0] == true && BotMiss[1] == true && BotMiss[2] == true && BotMiss[3] == true){
                        break; //Если уже были попытки выстрелить по всем сторонам
                    }
                }
            }
            else{ //При втором попадании стреляет в направлении, в котором раньше стрелял
                if (Direction == 1 && BotY > 0){
                    BotY--;
                }
                else if (Direction == 2 && BotX > 5){
                    BotX--;
                }
                else if (Direction == 3 && BotY < 9){
                    BotY++;
                }
                else if (Direction == 4 && BotX < 9){
                    BotX++;
                }
                else{
                    SecondBotHit = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            BotX = rand() % 4 + 5;
            BotY = rand() % 10;
        }
```

Это определит сторону выстрела.
Я заметил, что вы неправильно генерируете координаты и показываете их. Массивы начинаются с 0, а значит нам нужно генерировать

```
BotX = rand() % 4 + 5;
BotY = rand() % 10;
```

И показывать координаты вот так:

```
int CoutBotX = BotX + 1;
        int CoutBotY = BotY + 1;
        cout << "\t\t\t\tБот ввел координаты: x[" << CoutBotX << "] и y[" << CoutBotY << "]\n";
```

Чтобы ИИ не реагировал на убитые корабли добавляем вот такую часть кода в начале промаха:

```
if (field[BotX][BotY] != -1){
                cout << "\n\t\t\t\tБот промахнулся! Ваша очередь..." << endl;
                isMyRound = true;
            }
```

Записывает промах в одну из сторон и проверяет стрелял ли по всем четырём сторонам бот, а также возвращает координаты на попадание в корабль:

```
            BotHitForSecondBotHit = false;
            if (Direction != -1){
                BotMiss[Direction - 1] = true;
                if ((BotMiss[0] == true && BotMiss[1] == true && BotMiss[2] == true && BotMiss[3] == true) || SecondBotHit == true){
                    BotHit = false;
                    for (int x = 0; x != 4; x++){
                        BotMiss[x] = false;
                    }
                }
                if (SecondBotHit == false && BotHit == true){
                    if (Direction == 1){
                        BotY++; //Направляет координату правее
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 2){
                        BotX++; //Направляет координату ниже
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 3){
                        BotY--; //Направляет координату левее
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 4){
                        BotX--; //Направляет координату выше
                    }
                }
            }
            SecondBotHit = false;
```

Советую либо переместить в начало после проверки убитого корабля, либо убрать

```
field[i][j] = 0
```

Получается вот такой код:

```
while (isMyRound == false) // * ход бота
    {
        cout << "\t\tХод бота...\n\n";
        if (BotHit == true){
            if (SecondBotHit == false){
                while (true){
                    Direction = 1 + rand() % 4;
                    if (Direction == 1 && BotMiss[0] == false && BotY > 0){
                        BotY--; //Стреляет левее
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 2 && BotMiss[1] == false && BotX > 5){
                        BotX--; //Стреляет выше
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 3 && BotMiss[2] == false && BotY < 9){
                        BotY++; //Стреляет правее
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 4 && BotMiss[3] == false && BotX < 9){
                        BotX++; //Стреляет ниже
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        BotMiss[Direction - 1] = true; //Если никуда не получилось выстрелить
                    }
                    if (BotMiss[0] == true && BotMiss[1] == true && BotMiss[2] == true && BotMiss[3] == true){
                        break; //Если уже были попытки выстрелить по всем сторонам
                    }
                }
            }
            else{ //При втором попадании стреляет в направлении, в котором раньше стрелял
                if (Direction == 1 && BotY > 0){
                    BotY--;
                }
                else if (Direction == 2 && BotX > 5){
                    BotX--;
                }
                else if (Direction == 3 && BotY < 9){
                    BotY++;
                }
                else if (Direction == 4 && BotX < 9){
                    BotX++;
                }
                else{
                    SecondBotHit = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            BotX = rand() % 4 + 5;
            BotY = rand() % 10;
        }
        int CoutBotX = BotX + 1;
        int CoutBotY = BotY + 1;
        cout << "\t\t\t\tБот ввел координаты: x[" << CoutBotX << "] и y[" << CoutBotY << "]\n";

        if (field[BotX][BotY] == 1)
        {
            if (BotHit == true){
                BotHitForSecondBotHit = true;
            }
            if (BotHitForSecondBotHit == true){
                SecondBotHit = true;
            }
            BotHit = true;
            cout << "\n\t\t\t\tБот попал по нашему кораблю!\a" << endl;
            field[BotX][BotY] = 5;

            Sleep(5500);

            tableShow();

            field[BotX][BotY] = -1;

            bool ship_detect = false;
            for (int i = 6; i < SIZEf; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZEf; j++)
                {
                    if (field[i][j] == 1)
                    {
                        ship_detect = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (ship_detect == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ship_detect == false)
            {
                cout << "\t\t\t\tБот выиграл!!! Все наши корабли потеплены!" << endl;
                Sleep(5500);
                ad();
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (field[BotX][BotY] != -1){
                cout << "\n\t\t\t\tБот промахнулся! Ваша очередь..." << endl;
                isMyRound = true;
            }
            BotHitForSecondBotHit = false;
            if (Direction != -1){
                BotMiss[Direction - 1] = true;
                if ((BotMiss[0] == true && BotMiss[1] == true && BotMiss[2] == true && BotMiss[3] == true) || SecondBotHit == true){
                    BotHit = false;
                    for (int x = 0; x != 4; x++){
                        BotMiss[x] = false;
                    }
                }
                if (SecondBotHit == false && BotHit == true){
                    if (Direction == 1){
                        BotY++; //Направляет координату правее
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 2){
                        BotX++; //Направляет координату ниже
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 3){
                        BotY--; //Направляет координату левее
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 4){
                        BotX--; //Направляет координату выше
                    }
                }
            }
            SecondBotHit = false;
            Sleep(5500);
            tableShow();
        }
    } // *
```

Надеюсь я всё написал правильно и это поможет вам.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что разобрались в коде и разъяснили эти моменты. Но в коде есть ошибка из-за которой бот попадает по координатам, где нет "1" но показывается, что бот попал по моему кораблю. Также, он может переходить за грань своей карты когда делает второй выстрел подряд

Comment: @HikoMoff Дополнил и исправил код. Посмотрите ещё раз, должно работать.

Comment: можете, если не сложно сказать, что вы изменили? просто я сам не смог разобраться. У меня было 3 версии по которым возможна данная проблема. 1) Неправильно отображены корабли на карте 2) Ошибка в коде в ходе бота 3) Существуют корабли, которые есть в программе но не отображены на карте. Я проверил игру. Есть такой баг, что если бот попал на x[6], то он пойдет выше и перейдет границу. То есть, ударит по своему же полю. Также, после такого удара, бот забагался и стрелял только на своем поле, пока не забагался окончательно и была надпись Ход бота... (и все)

Comment: @HikoMoff При выводе куда попал бот вы уменьшаете координаты, а после проверяете. Я зачем-то их увеличил, уже не помню зачем и вычисления не совпадали с cout. Чтобы бот не выходил за границы экрана я проверил, где находится координата предыдущего выстрела

Comment: @HikoMoff Так как не знал неправильно сделал rand(). Проверьте часть кода с определением стороны выстрела

Comment: бот ввел координаты x[9] y[9] а потом x[8] y[7] (по сути должен был x[8] y[7]). Позже, бот ввел x[6] y[4] а после этого x[5] y[3] (должен был направо либо налево либо вниз, а не выходить за свою территорию атаки). Но иногда он правильно вводит последующие действия. Не знаю с чем связан этот баг

Comment: @HikoMoff Это произошло после того как вы обновили код после последнего изменения ответа?

Comment: Сейчас я проверил снова код. Бот ввел и попал по моему кораблю по координатам x[6] y[4], потом он ввел x[6] y[3] и промахнуля. Казалось бы все правильно, но после последующего моего хода и промаха, он ввел координаты x[5] y[3] которые находятся не на его поле атаки. Это меня удивило

Comment: @HikoMoff Я исправил все ошибки, но много времени на тестирование у меня нет. Массивы начинаются с 0, я исправил связанную с этим ошибку. Бот теперь стреляет вокруг убитого корабля правильно

Comment: обнаружил такую проблему после прошлого исправления, что после того как бот попадает по моему кораблю, он стреляет на 1 ячейку влево, но при этом не показывается - попал он или нет и потом он стреляет в случайном направлении куда-то и тут уже показывается - попал он или нет. Получается, когда он попадает - он стреляет 3 раза подряд в общем (если конечно второй раз он не попал)

Comment: @HikoMoff Повторный выстрел видел и исправил, но рандомного выстрела после одной попытки не нашёл. Баг с повторным выстрелом был потому что сначала так скажем "прицел" возвращался на координаты убитого корабля, а потом уже шла проверка попал бот в убитый корабль или в воду. Ещё я заметил баг, что при невозможности выстрелить во все четыре стороны бот уходит в вечный цикл и я это починил. Теперь убитые корабли тоже отображаются на поле. Надеюсь больше правок вносить мне не придётся